# trouble with linking an account in php

Tags: asp.net

Hello I am trying to link an account through creating a similar form from one on site to log into (`http://1betvegas.com/default.aspx`).  I am creating an interface where you will be able to link your account without actually having to go to site and you will be able to make bets and everything through interface.

My issue is that when I am sending over the data it is not logging in and I think it might have to do with the `onkeypress()` in the form section, but not to sure.

Code:

```
<form name='aspnetForm' method='post' action='http://1betvegas.com/default.aspx' onkeypress='javascript:return WebForm_FireDefaultButton(event, 'ctl00_MainContent_ctlLogin_BtnSubmit')' id='aspnetForm' style='margin: 0 0 0 0;'>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
            username: 
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name='ctl00$MainContent$ctlLogin$_UserName' type='text' size='15' id='ctl00_MainContent_ctlLogin__UserName' accesskey='u' tabindex='60' class='login_input'>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
            password: 
            </td>

            <td>
            <input name='ctl00$MainContent$ctlLogin$_IdBook' type='hidden' id='ctl00_MainContent_ctlLogin__IdBook'>
            <input name='ctl00$MainContent$ctlLogin$Redir' type='hidden' id='ctl00_MainContent_ctlLogin_Redir' value='wager/welcome.aspx'>
                <input name='ctl00$MainContent$ctlLogin$_Password' type='password' size='15' id='ctl00_MainContent_ctlLogin__Password' accesskey='p' tabindex='61' class='login_input'>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <input type='submit' name='ctl00$MainContent$ctlLogin$BtnSubmit' value='Login' id='ctl00_MainContent_ctlLogin_BtnSubmit' class='login_input' style='text-transform: uppercase;'>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

This code ---- all the input boxes and form are from the actual site.

Comment: so you use php.NET in the back end? and where is th onpress in this question

Comment: Its the onkeypress() in the <form section>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have errors in

```
onkeypress='javascript:return WebForm_FireDefaultButton(event, 'ctl00_MainContent_ctlLogin_BtnSubmit')'
```

change it to

```
onkeypress='javascript:return WebForm_FireDefaultButton(event, "ctl00_MainContent_ctlLogin_BtnSubmit")'
```

Notice the quotes and also this is not `php`, it's `asp.net`.

Comment: it gives me a error when I use the one you told me to change to - i am using echo to print this out, can I not? because of the fact its .asp?

Comment: `asp.net` has no `echo` but [Response.Write(string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525585.aspx) [also see this](http://naspinski.net/post/inline-aspnet-tags-sorting-them-all-out-%283c25242c-3c253d2c-3c252c-3c252c-etc%29.aspx).

Comment: No i am writing it in php so i was using echo to do the <form> and stuff

Comment: @DavidBiga, share it here what was the actual problem for future reference, may be you can update your question with that solution.